# impossible to connect to my DB with 2 instances of wordpress - swarm disabled?

Tags: wordpress, networking, load-balancing, traefik

I installed a 2 nodes one host docker + traefik for 2 wordpress instances. 
I want my instances to be available at the same time with 2 separated domain names. 3 docker-compose files are used :
1 for traefik  - 1 external network (NW1)
1 for wordpress 1 stack (domain1) - (NW1 + internal NW2)
1 for wordpress 2 stack (domain2) - (NW1 + internal NW3)

Currently I have a confusion between the databases, probably because of the network : 
If I start wordpress 1 compose-file  --> everything ok, . 
I start wordpress 2 : wordpress 1 database is not used anymore by wordpress1. I stop the wordpress2 docker-compose, wordpress1 access to DB again and I can connect on wp-admin as usual.

Of course I have created 2 separated internal networks for wp1 DB and wp2 DB, I verified with inspect.

Wordpress 1 backend network 1 :  "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16" ,  "Gateway": "172.18.0.1" ; wordpress 2 Backend network 2 : "Subnet": "192.168.80.0/20",  "Gateway": "192.168.80.1"

How to get my 2 wordpress instances isolated and working at the same time ?

I tried to change the network (using bridge or host), using internal flags, creating external network or using docker-compose network etc...
Doesn't change anything...

Exemple of configuration of a wordpress stack (YML file) :

```
version: '3'

networks:
  #domain2internal:
  #  driver: bridge
  #  external: false
  #  internal: true
 domain2internal:
    external:
      name: domain2
 prometheus:
    external:
      name: dockerprometheus_back-tier

services:

  domain2db:
    container_name: domain2db
    image: 'mariadb:latest'
    volumes:
      - '/storage/db/domain2:/var/lib/mysql'
     # - '/storage/db/prometheus/mysqld.cnf:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf'
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxx
      - MYSQL_USER=mariadb_wp
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxx
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=domain2_wp
#      - DB_PATH_HOST=/storage/db/domain2
    #  - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    expose:
      - 3306
    networks:
      - domain2internal

  wpdomain2wp:
    image: 'wordpress:latest'

  wpdomain2wp:
    image: 'wordpress:latest'
    volumes:
      - '/storage/www/www.domain2.asia:/var/www/html'
      - './uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini'
      - /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro
      - /etc/group:/etc/group:ro
      #- './wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content'
    depends_on:
      - domain2db
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=domain2db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=mariadb_wp
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=domain2_wp
      - MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP=3306
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    labels:
      - "traefik.entrypoint=https"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.domain2.asia, domain2.co, project.domain2.asia"
      - "traefik.frontend.redirect.regex=^https?://domain2.asia/(.*)"
      - "traefik.frontend.redirect.replacement=https://www.domain2.asia/$${1}"
      - "traefik.frontend.redirect.permanent=true"
      - "traefik.backend=wordpress"
      - "traefik.docker.network=prometheus"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - traefik.port=80
    networks:
      - prometheus
      - domain2internal
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: `I start wordpress 2 : wordpress 1 database is not used anymore by wordpress1`. How do you know that? What I suggest you do is to drop into your wp shell and use linux command line tools for verifying dns and connection to your database. Stay in shell make sure it can resolve and connect check the ip. Up the second one, repeat the same and see what's broken, name resolution, different ip, same ip but port is closed, etc - narrow down your problem.

Comment: Quite likely that when you copy-pasted your config for the second instance you forgot to change something in it so both instances has the same "object" that they are not supposed to share.

Comment: I followed your advice and found the problem : traefik.backend was linked to the other container

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this I suggest you drop into your Wordpress container shell and use Linux command line tools for verifying DNS and connection to your database. Stay in shell make sure it can resolve and connect check the IP. Up the second one, repeat the same and see what's broken, name resolution, different IP, same IP but port is closed, etc - narrow down your problem.

Quite likely that when you copy-pasted your config for the second instance you forgot to change something in it so both instances has the same "object" that they are not supposed to share.